# Programmatically Convert all AWS inline policies to Managed Policies of current IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Currently I have several hundred AWS IAM Roles with inline policies.

I would like to somehow convert these inline policies to managed policies.

While [AWS Documentation has a way to do this via the Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html), this will be very time consuming.

Does anyone know of a way, or have a script to do this via BOTO or AWS CLI...or direct me to some method that I can do this programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do this, be aware that there are a limited number of managed policies that can be attached to a role (10 by default, 20 if you request a limit increase from AWS). Inline policies are often used to work-around this limitation, because they're limited only by size.

Comment: And if you simply move the inline policies into a new managed policy named after the role, you've doubled the number of objects that you're managing and are getting no real benefit.

Comment: @Parsifal I literally have 1 (max 2 in some occasion) inline policy per IAM Role. Unfortunately, replacing In-line policies with Managed instead is a requirement per HIPAA and SOC2. 
Ref:
(164.308(a)(3)(i))
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/operational-best-practices-for-hipaa_security.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boto3 code will be like this.

In this code, inline policies that are embedded *in the specified IAM user* will be copied to customer managed policies.

Note delete part is commented out.

```py
import json

import boto3

user_name = 'xxxxxxx'

client = boto3.client("iam")

response = client.list_user_policies(UserName=user_name)


for policy_name in response["PolicyNames"]:

    response = client.get_user_policy(UserName=user_name, PolicyName=policy_name)
    policy_document = json.dumps(response["PolicyDocument"])

    response = client.create_policy(
        PolicyName=policy_name, PolicyDocument=policy_document_json
    )

    # response = client.delete_user_policy(
    #     UserName=user_name,
    #     PolicyName=policy_name
    # )
```

**Updated:**

For IAM roles, changing `User` to `Role`, `user` to `role` (case sensitive) above code works.

Besides, if you execute for multiple roles, use list_roles to get `role_name`.

```py
response=client.list_roles()

for i in response['Roles']:
    role_name = i['RoleName']
    # print(role_name)
```

Comment: Thanks @shimo

However your BOTO3 addresses the inline policies on an IAM user, I am specifically looking for inline policies attached to IAM Roles.

Comment: Updated some code. Just small change will work.

Comment: I also think that:

'PolicyDocument=policy_document_json'

should be:

 'PolicyDocument=policy_document'

If you can add also how to attached the newly created Managed policy to the IAM role it would be a bonus (was not in original post).

Answer (score 0):

with @shimo snippet, the following works with added error handling and attaching the newly created managed policy to the IAM role:

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

role_name = 'xxxxxxxx'
account_id = '123456789'

client = boto3.client("iam")
resource = boto3.resource('iam')

response = client.list_role_policies(RoleName=role_name)

for policy_name in response["PolicyNames"]:
    response = client.get_role_policy(RoleName=role_name, PolicyName=policy_name)
    policy_document = json.dumps(response["PolicyDocument"])
    print(policy_document)
    try:
        response = client.create_policy(
            PolicyName=policy_name, PolicyDocument=policy_document
        )
        print(policy_name + 'Policy Created')
    except ClientError as error:
        if error.response['Error']['Code'] == 'EntityAlreadyExists':
            print(policy_name + ' policy already exists')
        else:
            print("Unexpected error: %s" % error)

    policy_arn = f'arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:policy/{policy_name}'
    role = resource.Role(role_name)
    role.attach_policy(PolicyArn=policy_arn)

    response = client.delete_role_policy(
        RoleName=role_name,
        PolicyName=policy_name
    )
```